# how to get vocabulary of CountVectorizer using pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, countvectorizer

usually when I use `CountVectorizer` only, I can has the vocabulary that I can us it as parameter for the new object of `CountVectorizer` to prossessing new data before the predict

```py
cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
cv_dict = cv.vocabulary_
test_cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = cv_dict)
test_X= test_cv.fit_transform(test_corpus).toarray()
```

I want to know how can do the same thing using pipeline?
I write this code to start

```py
text_features = dataset['corpus']
text_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('count', CountVectorizer()),
    ]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('text', text_transformer, text_features[0])
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet to create the `test_cv` vectorizer is overcomplicated and unnecessary. It may also give different vectors that you expect. Let us first simplify that and the pipeline part will become easier. You created the `cv` object and used its `fit_transform` function. This function fits the vectorizer to the data. in this case, it means that it learns the vocabulary of the data and stores it internally in the `vocabulary` instance variable. It then transforms the input data according to the vocabulary it learned while fitting.

If you now simply called the `transform` function on the same object, it would use the stored vocabulary to transform the new data as well. You do not need to create a new object `test_cv` and pass the old vocabulary to it.

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
test_X= cv.transform(test_corpus).toarray()
```

Now that this is simplified, the pipeline part becomes easier to understand. Your pipeline code already works in its current state (provided the inputs are correct). You can now call `processor.fit(corpus)` if you want the vectorizer to learn the vocabulary. You can then call `processor.transform(test_corpus)` to apply the vectorizer to the test_corpus.